# C++: link error with static const variables in template class

Tags: c++, templates

I'm developing a class that receive as parameter a template class object. Since it has a template object, I'm defining all methods in the .h file (no .cpp).

I have static const variables that I declare in .h file and I initialize them in the .cpp file (this is the only purpose of the .cpp file in my case). I access these static const variables in some methods.

I can compile this class without problems. The problem appears when I try to include the header file in the file that will execute it, then I have the following error:

```
UnitTest.obj : Error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static char const * const A::FNUMBER
```

I have tried to define methods in the .cpp file, but then when I try to compile I have linker errors in all methods of the mentioned template class.

Here an example of code:

---

### Header file (.h)

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include "TemplateClass.h"

typedef TemplateClass<int, char> A_TemplateClass;

class A{

    public:
        static const float FNUMBER;

        //Due to I refer a template class, I have to implement all my methods in .h file,
        //else I have a lot of linker errors (1 for each template class method)
        A(A_TemplateClass &atc) : aTemplateClass(atc) {};

        void method1(){
            //Use the static const variable
            //If I do not access this variable, there is no problems.
            float f = FNUMBER + 3.2;
            [...]
        }

        void method2(){
            //Use the static const variable
            //If I do not access this variable, there is no problems.
            float f = FNUMBER + 3.3;
            [...]
        }


    private:
        A_TemplateClass aTemplateClass;

};


#endif
```

---

### .cpp file

```
#include "A.h"

const float A::FNUMBER = 1.3f;
```

---

### UnitTest.cpp file

```
#include "TemplateClass.h"
#include "A.h"

int main(){
    TemplateClass<int, char> x;
    A a(x);
    float f = A::FNUMBER; //Linker ERROR
    //If I delete the above line, there are no errors.
}
```

As I say, If I do not use the static const variables inside the class, there are no errors.
What I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Is your `UnitTest.cpp` being linked to your `.cpp` file that contains the definition for `A::FNUMBER`? It's possible you're not linking your unit test against the implementation file(s).

Comment: after putting `;` instead of `.` in the end of the `typedef`, and terminating class `A` with `;` - this compiles perfectly.

Comment: Is the `A_TemplateClass`, `method1`, `method2`, etc. stuff really relevant to the problem at hand? Or could you remove them to create a better [**Minimal**, Complete, and **Verifiable** example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Because as is, this doesn't look minimal or verifiable (given the syntax errors Arnon Zilca just pointed out).

Comment: SIntax erros fixed. Actually, In my real class, I have the  ;  at the end of the class and a  ;  instead of  .  at the end of typedef. The method1 and method2 are only relevant to show that I have a linker error If I try to access the static const variables.

Comment: Note that In my case, the class compiles, the error appears only when I try to include it from UnitTest.cpp

Comment: If the problem is that `UnitTest.cpp` is not being linked to my `.cpp`, how can I solve It?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including the `.cpp` file which contains the `static const` variables initialization the problem is solved.

Comment: Then that for sure sounds like you're not linking. You should do what weavr and I suggested: link your compiled files.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are compiling/linking with A.cpp/A.o? Your code should compile with `g++ UnitTest.cpp A.cpp` assuming TemplateClass.h doesn't have an external .cpp file.

Comment: I'm sure that the TemplateClass has not .cpp file. I'm using Visual Studio for compile.

Comment: I have all method implementation in the .h file, Is possible that the problem is that the linker do not search the `static const` variable definition in the .cpp file?

Comment: I have added to the UnitTest.cpp file a `#include "A.cpp"` and now all works. I do not understand why I need to add that `include`. Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: I'm guessing that you are not compiling the A.cpp file or you are not linking with the A.obj file.

Comment: I'm suggesting not to include .cpp files. I think that it is bad practice. It would be better to fix your build command by adding A.cpp to the sources.

Comment: I'm agree, but I don't know how to add the .cpp file to the Visual Studio compiler, the .cpp files is already in the source files folder (in the project), what else do I have to do ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with Visual Studio as I don't use it.

Comment: I think it's not important, but actually the `class A` is in a project and the `UnitTest.cpp` in other project, both projects inside the same solution.